# CentOS 6: не работает кнопка "выключить"

Tags: centos

Кнопка "выключить" не работает. Что надо сделать и что подправить чтоб заработало,подскажите кто знает. В какую сторону глядеть

Answer (score 1):

Ответ подзадержался, но всёже. Посмотри в управление питанием. И не плохо было бы посмотреть что показывает терминал при нажатии кнопки выключить.